# jQueryUI autocomplete with PHP and JSON

Tags: php, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, mysqli

I have a simple search box that is going to set a user's location from available entries in my database. I'm trying to get jQuery UI's autocomplete to work but am running into issues. With the JavaScript Console turned on in Chrome I see no response from the script as I begin to type.

The desired result is a dropdown autocomplete list that lists cities in "City, State" format. I've looked at several posts here on SO and have modified my code in many attempts to resolve this issue but no luck. Thanks in advance to any guidance / fixes. Much appreciated.

Here's my jQuery UI code (I am using the most current libraries hosted by code.jquery.com)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#locale').autocomplete(
    {
        source: "./state_autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 2
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's my form code:

```
<form name="frm_set_locale" method="post" action="/index2.php">
  <input type="text" name="locale" id="locale" class="textbox">
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="frm_submit_locale" value="Search">
</form>
```

And here's the mysqli script that pulls the information

```
<?php
include "/includes/dbconn.php";

// Query to get the usable locations
    $locale = trim($_GET['term']);
    $return = array();

    $q = "SELECT `city`, `state` FROM `locales` WHERE `city` LIKE '%".$locale."%'";
    $r = mysqli_query($q, $connect);

    $json = "[";
    $first = true;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r, $connect)){
        if(!$first){
            $json .=  ",";
        }else{
            $first = false;
        }

        $json .= "{'value':'".$row['city'].", ".$row['state']."}";
    }

    $json .= "]";

    echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: You're Not POSTING the request

Comment: Understood. The post is the method for after they choose a result from the jqueryui autocomplete. The value selected from the state_autocomplete.php script will then be posted by the user when they click on submit.

Comment: Indeed, but you've to 1st `request` for `Json data` to come back as `Object` to set the source of your `UI AutoComplete`.
<br/>

See the below code..

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are generating invalid JSON--you need a "key" for the "state" value.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker, that was my thinking but all the examples I've seen for this autocomplete with remote data source only use on field returned in the SQL query so I'm not sure how to add the secondary key.

Comment: Yeah indeed.. A `LITERAL` for state value is required too!

Comment: @rsmith84: The same way you did it for "value"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. I took a new approach to the state_autocomplete.php and here is what got it working for me. Really clean.

```
<?php
// Database Connection
    include "/includes/dbconn.php";

// Query to get the usable locations
    $locale = $_GET['term'];

    $q = "SELECT `city`, `state` FROM `locales` WHERE `city` LIKE '%$locale%'";
    $r = mysqli_query($connect, $q);            

    $city_state = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
        $result = $row['city'].", ".$row['state'];
        array_push($city_state, $result);
    }
    $json = json_encode($city_state);
    echo $json;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

1st A Literal for State value is required..

```
"{'value':'".$row['city'].", 'state':".$row['state']."}"
```

2nd You've to request data by Ajax post

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
          $.ajax({
               url: '/state_autocomplete.php',
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(data){
                     $('#locale').autocomplete(
                     {
                           source: data,
                           minLength: 2
                     });
               }
          });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This results in the same error. If I go to http://www.mydomain.com/state_autcomplete.php?term=ph for example, I get an empty result set even though there are a few cities listed with "ph" in their name in the database so I'm wondering if the issues is with the state_autocomplete.php script.

Answer (score 0):

The auto complete function you're using doesn't do an ajax call with the query string as you intended from `<input type="text" name="locale" id="locale" class="textbox">`

For it work change

```
$q = "SELECT `city`, `state` FROM `locales` WHERE `city` LIKE '%".$locale."%'";
```

to

```
$q = "SELECT `city`, `state` FROM `locales`";
```

The script will then generate all the cities and states then the auto complete function will match on the users input.